# Speeding up my for loop that builds vector element by element by comparing with element above

Tags: r

i'm building a little simulation in R to do some analysis on. Building a vector element by element by comparing it to the element above and another vector. Picking the largest of the two and adding a number.

However it is very slow because of the for loop. I'm hoping there are ways to speed this up(vectorizing? apply? aggregate?)

This is the part that needs fixing:

```
number_of_jobs = 100000 
arrival_rate = 1 
service_rate = 2 
job_in = cumsum(rexp(number_of_jobs, rate = arrival_rate)) 
servicetimes = rexp(number_of_jobs, rate = service_rate) #first job has no waiting time 

#initialize first job
job_out = vector()
job_out[1] = job_in[1] + servicetimes[1] 
#loop over all remaining jobs.
for (i in 2:number_of_jobs){
    job_out[i] = max(job_out[i-1], job_in[i])  + servicetimes[i]
}
```

Comment: Could you make your example reproducible?

Comment: +1 for reproducible example. First order of business: Preallocate `job_out`! E.g., `job_out <- numeric(number_of_jobs)`. If that doesn't result in a sufficient speed-up, your `for` loop would be trivial to translate to Rcpp. Or there might already be a vectorized solution as suggested in the answer.

Comment: number_of_jobs = 100000
arrival_rate = 1
service_rate = 2
job_in = cumsum(rexp(number_of_jobs, rate = arrival_rate))


servicetimes = rexp(number_of_jobs, rate = service_rate)

#first job has no waiting time
job_out = vector()
job_out[1] = job_in[1] + servicetimes[1]

#loop over all remaining jobs
for (i in 2:number_of_jobs){
  job_out[i] = max(job_out[i-1], job_in[i])  + servicetimes[i]
}

Comment: Preallocating helped a lot! Thanks